# How to increase the performance of multiple filesize() calls?

Tags: php, performance

I have the following situation in PHP:

```
$paths = [
    "/dir/file1" => false,
    "/dir/file2" => false,
    "/dir/file3" => false,
    "/dir/file4" => false,
];
foreach ($paths as $path => $_) {
    if (filesize($path) > 100) {
        echo "$path is larger than 100 bytes\n";
    }
}
```

This works well for local filesystems, but when used in combination with remote file systems (we use SMB) it gets slow because each `filesize` is synchronous and does a network roundtrip.

How can I speed this up? Preferably without an extension, but that's also an option.

Comment: I guess the question is actually how to get file size information in batch using SMB protocol. Perhaps you should make it more obvious both in title and tags to call the attention of potential answerers.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I would like to avoid making it SMB-specific as we have some folders that are remote and some that are local. I was thinking maybe there's an iterator in PHP that prefetches results or something like `scandir` that returns the file size.

Comment: I understand. Fair enough.

Comment: Does this prefetch? https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getsize.php

Comment: @nice_dev [I don't think so.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6b1337b736c8fcae860d15ab3ff853939e6b38bf/ext/spl/spl_directory.c#L1182)

Comment: Hmm . Then in the UI, you can show them in the batches of 5, load the next batch if only requested by the user.